# Sort records from types Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, haml

Hi im trying to sort output data without the controller in the layout, im using devise, formtastic and some other gems to make the login and user interface

the problem is that i have 3 tables Products, Carted_products and Users, and i want to show the Carted_products by Product_id in the view, i got already it to show them by record in the table but i want it to SORT them example:

I have 3 different orders, 2 of them have the same product_id, they have each:

1. Ammount
2. Product_id
3. User_id

and i can acces the price via carted_product.product in the model asociation

heres my view code:

> %tbody
>
> > ```
> >      - if user_signed_in?
> >        - current_user.carted_products.each do |f|
> >          - @total = @total + f.carted_product_price(f.ammount, f.product.price)
> >          %tr
> >            %td.carted_name
> >              = f.product.name
> >            %td.carted_ammount
> >              = f.ammount
> >            %td.carted_price  
> >              $ 
> >              = f.carted_product_price(f.ammount, f.product.price)
> > ```

carted_product_price just recieves the ammount and price of the product and returns the multiplied price

so it prints all the rows in the table it doesnt matter if the different records are form the same product, i just want to join them in only one table row output

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: well it prints all the records in "carted_products" from an specified user("current_user"), the records are added by buy orders so it prits each order, it doesnt matter if they are the same product, so i want to join all the orders from one product in a single row print, instead of printing a row for each order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to iterate through the products, not the carted products. Personally, I'd move most of this logic to the model.

```
class Product
  ...
  def carted_products_total_amount
    carted_products.inject(0) {|acc, amount| acc + amount }
  end

  def total
    carted_product_price(carted_products_total_amount, price)
  end
end
```

And then in the view:

```
%tbody
   - current_user.products.each do |product|
     - @total = @total + product.total
     %tr
       %td.carted_name
         = product.name
       %td.carted_amount
         = product.carted_products_total_amount
       %td.carted_price  
         $ 
         = product.total
```

Also, the correct spelling of "amount" only includes a single "m" character. ;)